# How can we paste in Cygwin with right-click?

Tags: cygwin, copy-paste, paste, putty

We're more familiar with PuTTY, so we use right-click more often to paste the text.

And sometimes when a session times out or closes, everything on the console is wiped out, so we use [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) with more functions and controls to automate our tasks.

Comment: This depends on what terminal you are using. For instance, I'm using `mintty` (highly recommended), with Cygwin, and configure which button is used for pasting. Most terminal applications nowadays have a way to configure at least some mouse interaction.

Comment: I just noticed from the answer you gave to your own question, that you do seem to use _mintty_  anyway.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Cygwin window bar → *Options* → *Mouse* → *Click actions* → select the **Paste** radio button.

[image: Screenshot]

Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>Save</kbd>, and close the window.

You are done now. Test and check!

Comment: Is "Apply" necessary?

Comment: you can save directly :)  , apply is useful just in case if you want to test it before closing the option window.